# how to check number in percentage and print it in an array or object, if number is exits then it should return 1 otherwise 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

in a array of [5,10,15,20,40]. we need to check the number with % and if we get 5 and 10 then we will take it in 10% and print it 1 so for 10 to 20 we consider as 20% and check the number if we get any number from there then we will increase the number like wise we need to calculate.
for example [ 10, 4, 40, 50, 70] the max number is 100 so that's the 100th% and the result should be [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] there is 1 element in 0-10% (4), 1 in 10-20% (10), none in 20-30%, and so forth. –

```
function calculating_marks(x) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i] <= 10 ? console.log("1") : console.log("0")
    x[i] > 10 && x[i] <= 20 ? console.log("1") : console.log("0")
    x[i] > 20 && x[i] <= 30 ? console.log("1") : console.log("0")
    x[i] > 30 && x[i] <= 40 ? console.log("1") : console.log("0")
    x[i] > 40 && x[i] <= 50 ? console.log("1") : console.log("0")
    x[i] > 50 && x[i] <= 60 ? console.log("1") : console.log("0")
  }
}

marks = [5,10,20,30,35,50]
calculating_marks(marks)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a solution to your question, I hope it solves your problem:

```
function calculating_marks(marks) {
  const marksResult = Array(10).fill(0);
  for (const mark of marks) {
    let markConverted = Math.floor(mark/10) - 1;
    if(markConverted === -1){
      markConverted++;
    }
    marksResult[markConverted]++;
  }
    return marksResult;
}

let marks = [5,10,20,30,35,50]
let marksConverted = calculating_marks(marks)
console.log(marksConverted)
```

Comment: what's complex here? Sounds good to me

Comment: this might be not correct, because obviously 50 must be included in range 90-100%, but result of function above is [2,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 0):

Save in a array and plus if true

```
function calculating_marks(x) {
   // count for 10%,20%,.....100%
   var count = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
   for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i] <= 10 ? count[0]++ :
    x[i] > 10 && x[i] <= 20 ? count[1]++ : 
    x[i] > 20 && x[i] <= 30 ? count[2]++ : 
    x[i] > 30 && x[i] <= 40 ? count[3]++ : 
    x[i] > 40 && x[i] <= 50 ? count[4]++ : 
    x[i] > 50 && x[i] <= 60 ? count[5]++ : false
   }
  console.log(count);
}

marks = [5,10,20,30,35,50]
calculating_marks(marks)

//Result (10) [2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach with inline comments:

```js
// Your function with custom calculation
const weirdCalculator = arr => {
  // Find largest number
  const largest = arr.sort((a,b) => a-b).reverse()[0];
  
  // Find 10% of largest number
  const p10 = Math.round(largest / 10);
  
  // Create result array
  const res = [];
  
  // Loop 10 times
  for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // With each new iteration add 10% and check
    // all numbers, passed to function, in loop
    // Calculate current range
    const currentRange = [(i - 1) * p10, i * p10];
    // Reset current iteration counter
    let counter = 0;
    // Loop numbers, passed to function
    // If number in current range - increase counter
    for(const num of arr) if(num > currentRange[0] && num <= currentRange[1]) counter++;
    // Push counter to result array
    res.push(counter);
  }
  
  // Return result
  return res;
}

// Run function
const result = weirdCalculator([5,10,20,31,34,50]);

// Test
console.log(result);
```